# How to increase the speed of a php function that returns a token

Tags: php, performance, optimization, refactoring, file-access

Good day,

There's a file named "bfile" that has binary values like this:

```
7f45 4c46 0201 0103 0000 0000 0000 0000
0200 3e00 0100 0000 300c 4000 0000 0000
4000 0000 0000 0000 5062 0c00 0000 0000
0000 0000 4000 3800 0500 4000 1f00 1c00
0100 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

The size of the file is 814KB. We're not allowed to change the binary in any way.

The function that access that is like this:

```
function get_auth_token() {
    $arg = json_encode($_REQUEST);
    return `./bfile $arg`;
}
```

Based on the function it's returning a token like this "z6x6ti5taac1mjn-9wG7w44-" but I don't how that works and how I can increase the speed.

With my current test, the result is this:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.7
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8000

Document Length:        38 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   201.117 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      226000 bytes
HTML transferred:       38000 bytes
Requests per second:    4.97 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2011.172 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       201.117 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.10 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:     5 1995 1434.6   2010    4055
Waiting:        4 1994 1434.5   2009    4054
Total:          5 1995 1434.6   2010    4055

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   2010
  66%   3009
  75%   3012
  80%   4006
  90%   4010
  95%   4013
  98%   4018
  99%   4022
 100%   4055 (longest request)
```

For a thousand request it took 201 seconds to finish.
I have to improve the design to make it handle several thousand requests per second. I have no idea how to do that. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like that file is a binary blob, an executable something doing internal voodoo which you cannot understand or alter. In that case the answer clearly is: "there is nothing you can do". Closed source binary blobs are a terrible thing. Maybe that thing even posts all your user data to some evil company. You do not know.

Comment: A file with 814KB does not only contain the code mentioned on your question (Much much more). Like @Arkascha said, who knows what is in the file. Can you post more info on that file? Maybe you can use a simple read code with php to get only the data you really need, not processing the rest. This could be a better approach.

Comment: Is the output of that blob reproduceable? So does it output the same string for identical input each time called? If so you could create yourself a dictionary inside a database you fill with all possible input/output combinations. Access to that will be million times faster.

Comment: @CarlosR it's too long can't paste it here. But the entire file contains only values like that.

Comment: @arkascha No, it produces different values everytime it's called. It's a placeholder for external process and API calls we have no control over.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do. You need to execute that blob once for each request, nothing in that you can speed up without deeper knowledge of that thing.

Comment: Then this means you have to process the entire file. Then in this case, is my approach no solution for you.

Comment: FYI, this is a [ELF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (Executable and Linkable Format).

Comment: @Danny_ds Hi Danny, thanks for the info. Do you know how I can make this work fast?

Comment: As mentioned above, there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

If it still makes sense, there would be something you could do to increase the amount of request you can handle : use php fpm, easier to setup with nginx, to be able to call [fastcgi_finish_request()](http://php.net/fastcgi_finish_request) as soon as you receive the request and returned the response status. This way, the rest of the script would be executed in background without keeping the connection slot.
This should increase your request rate, but it may still not be enough. If so, you would need to scale horizontally by load balancing the target API endpoint over several servers, and probably, to use a queue/worker pattern if what you need to do involves loading some data to some repo that could also be overwhelmed by the load when it's too high.

The whole thing is also achievable with apache and without fpm, but it's a bit more complicated as you need to set every bit of the response right to actually free the connection artificially.